# Good calculus library for C++?

Tags: library, c++, math

I want to calculate pi accurately to a million digits or even more and I came across the [Chudnovsky algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm) and I want to use it but it requires summation calculus. So what is the best library for doing this that works with https://gmplib.org/ and or https://mpfr.loria.fr/ ?

Comment: I found this, don't know if it will help

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.partow.net/programming/sumtk/index.html&ved=2ahUKEwiP2LKNku_3AhVnIbcAHY9fCwkQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0mUbH3NLt-ZVy6oDrN0gPV